# Solution to remain anonymous on a website that dismiss tor users?

Tags: privacy, proxy, tor

I want to access to a website who recognize tor users and dismiss them. I have read that if you connect to a proxy after your tor exit node, the website wouldn't know that you are a tor user and accept you. Essentially, I want to build a connection of the following form:

```
My computer -----> Tor -------> Free Proxy ------> Website
```

What I have done :

- edit the .torrc file to add a proxy = failed
- add manually a http proxy in the Tor Browser's preferences = failed (the Tor Button goes red with a cross on the onion)
- edit the etc/proxychains.conf to add a socks4 proxy and type proxychains firefox in a shell = failed with DNS errors, google.com does not exist

What is the best solution to do so ?

Answer (score 2):

Tor -> Startpage search -> view by Ixquick Proxy. This always worked for me the few times I've needed it.
or just use https://ixquick.com search engine instead of Startpage.
[image]

As for setting Tor up to do this automatically without the hassle, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Proxychains should work just fine. Your problem is definitely a configuration error.

Just to be complete, another solution would be, while anonymous via Tor, to rent a machine with a publicly routable IP and use that as a proxy. Depending on your anonymity requirements and the service provider's ToS you may need to use a prepaid credit card, Bitcoins (a clean wallet with the BTCs earned anonymously) and eventually forge some fake scans for ID documents if the provider asks you (nothing *morally* wrong with this if you're just seeking anonymity but aren't doing anything illegal).

A nice benefit of my solution is that most open proxies' IPs are listed (or get listed quite quickly) on lots of blacklists which means if the site blocks Tor users there's a good chance known proxies will be blocked too (or at the very least may alert the admin's suspicions when he learns that you're using a proxy), where as most server's IPs are clean besides email spam blacklists which don't apply to your use case.

Comment: -1 This is a bad idea. Using proxychains prevents the browser from doing per-site stream isolation (normally enforced by using a "password" automatically in the SOCKS protocol that triggers using a new stream).

Answer (score 1):

Before searching via Internet, I was thinking about it; what about creating virtual machine inside a virtual machine (*nested vms*) and use different VPN for each of them. At the end,

*Is it more secure or just making 'tortoise' Internet speed?*

After searching, I found a guy who *claims* that using nested VMs with VPN chain is a complete solution for anonymity.
Link is here:[*How to Chain VPNs for complete Anonymity*](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/chain-vpns-for-complete-anonymity-0131368/)

- First, install VPN to your host computer
- And install any of the Virtual Machine you want
- Then, install Tor to your Guest Virtual Machine
- Start VPN from your host computer
- Use Tor installed to Guest Machine to access that website

Comment: And how it is going to solve the problem that OP is facing? If the VirtualBox is using bridged network, the guest will completely bypass the host network NIC and communicate with the router directly. If it is a NAT network, the host will provide NAT service, first connect to VPN A, after that the Tor circuit will be established which will connect to the website. It will have the IP address of the Tor exit node nevertheless. So what have you achieved?

Comment: Tor-VPN are interchangeable; if you use NAT, and using VPN installed on guest but routing all traffic through Tor Network in host, is it still useless?

Comment: If you use VPN to connect to the Tor network, the entry node of Tor (Tor uses three nodes) will get the VPN IP and traffic to the website will still exit through the Tor exit node which will be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

The site is probably just checking whether your IP address is in the known list of Tor exit nodes.

A pretty much identical question exists here : https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/how-to-chain-proxy-after-tor

While I somewhat question your motivation (are you attempting to bypass this block due to you actually being a spammer?), I'm going to err on the side of this being a legitimate request (and besides a website owner will still block whatever proxy IP you come out of if you abuse the site on the new IP address).

Most of the Tor proxy links I could find are for users trying to use a proxy BEFORE Tor, you need to use Tor to connect to a proxy server on the internet AFTER going through Tor.

As you mentioned something web-based you could visit while using Tor something like www.hidemyass.com to then appear to come out of the HideMyAss range instead of Tor.

The reason changing the proxy settings in your browser didn't work is because Tor behaves like a proxy server, so removing the Tor settings and providing just a normal proxy stopped it from going through Tor (unless that proxy itself goes through Tor).

I don't know if this already exists (this site suggests it does : https://www.deepdotweb.com/security-tutorials/chain-socks-tor/) but making a program to behave like a proxy server that then connects to a proxy server via the Tor proxy server would work, you would specify this relay as the proxy in your web-browser and then leave it to this new program to set up the connection to the proxy on the other side after going through Tor.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is a bit old, I think it is getting more relevant as time passes. Because it very much looks as if more and more websites are blocking Tor exit nodes. And I'm afraid none of the options is actually without (sometimes serious) flaws:

- You put a proxy after the exit node with proxychains. This does work, I have tried it myself. But sites that block Tor seem to be very good at also blocking proxy ips. (At least the public and free proxies.)
- As suggested in another answer you could rent a VPS and make it your own proxy by installing a socks proxy server there. This can actually make you susceptible to correlation attacks, because instead of a randomly chosen exit node you now have a static endpoint (your VPS). That means if you routinely connect to your VPS (or rented proxy) right after you start Tor, you may get deanonymized.
- You put a VPN after Tor because VPNs seem to better evade blacklisting and you can randomly choose your endpoints. You can do this using Whonix and it will involve VMs. You will have to make sure the VPN does not have anything that could be linked to you (like traceable payment) and you will still increase risk of identity correlation. Some description is here: 
  https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Tunnels/Connecting_to_Tor_before_a_VPN

You could also do stuff like VPN->Tor->VPN or even use I2P after Tor, but all this will require some technical effort and has its downsides. The Whonix creators actually made a pretty good job writing this all down:
https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Tunnels/Introduction